# How to update content and id of div by jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to make fb style posting
how to set div id using content from server
create div and update content is ok

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="media" id="?????"> 
           // updated content here
    </div>

    // following DIVs exciting
    <div class="media" id="uuid"></div>
    <div class="media" id="uuid"></div>
    <div class="media" id="uuid"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit-305008493").bind("click", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                $("#sending").fadeIn();
                $("#desMediaContainer").prepend("<div class=\"media translationMedia\" id=\"dsf\"></div>");
            },
            data: $("#submit-305008493").closest("form").serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#sending").fadeOut();
                $("#desMediaContainer .translationMedia:first-child").html(data);
            },
            type: "post",
            url: "\/trans\/destinations\/add\/52104adf-4c88-4825-aa3f-0efcc282aae9"
        });
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: ID of an element must be unique, you cannot have more than 1 element with id uuid

Comment: Your code references `#desMediaContainer`, but that doesn't appear in your HTML. Is that what you're asking how to fix?

Comment: yes all id unique. I am trying to use newly created content uuid for new div.

Comment: desMediaContainer = container sorry my englsih.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.Thank you all. Its my fault. It was very easy.
Its solution is just prepend hole content to container and ready to delete edit.

```
$('#container).append(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

While you haven't provided enough information to actually indicate WHERE you should be pulling data from, you do need to pull it from somewhere. You can specify the URL in load, as well as define data parameters or a callback function.

```
$("#getCameraSerialNumbers").click(function () {
    $("#step1Content").load('YourUrl');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The html that you've written doesn't correspond with the javascript that you've written (different ids).

But going along with your javascript, why don't you just move the creation of your div from the beforeSend function right into the success function?

```
success: function (data, textStatus) {
    $("#desMediaContainer").prepend("<div class="media translationMedia" id="dsf"></div>");
    $("#desMediaContainer #dsf").html(data);
}
```

Comment: how to get id from new data.

Comment: You need to clarify the format of the data that is being returned.  When you call this url: "/trans/destinations/add/52104adf-4c88-4825-aa3f-0efcc282aae9", what exactly is the format of the data being returned?  Does that data include the id?  Can you post an example of the data that comes back?

Answer (score 0):

what ever the data returns it'll be in the html format like:

```
in php:
echo "div class=\"someclass\">content/div";
and in jquery:
use: $("#retdata").html(data);
```